# Newline character in StringBuilder

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

How do you append a new line(\n\r) character in `StringBuilder`?

Comment: That's not a newline under any common OS.  Windows is \r\n, Mac is \r, Unix and Linux are \n.

Comment: Pedantically 'newline' is always '\n'. It was the platten shift character in mechanical teletypes. 'carriage return' is always '\r'. It was the carriage return character in teletypes. Each operating system may interpret them differently. In Unix/Linux the return is generally not used because it's unnecessary because it's no longer a mechanical system.

Comment: @Jay: A character causing only platen shift is not referred to as newline, but linefeed.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I would make use of the [Environment.NewLine property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx).

Something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("Foo{0}Bar", Environment.NewLine);
string s = sb.ToString();
```

Or

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("Foo");
sb.Append("Foo2");
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append("Bar");
string s = sb.ToString();
```

If you wish to have a new line after each append, you can have a look at [Ben Voigt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617752/newline-character-in-stringbuilder/2617767#2617767).

Comment: It's possible to mix Append and AppendLine to get new lines where you want them, not after every Append.  Also, I linked to the zero-argument version of AppendLine which appends nothing but the newline sequence.

Comment: I have been trapped by append then appendline. I expected appendline to add a \n then my string, but appendline appends the string then the \n - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline.aspx

Comment: Stringbuilder.AppendLine() does the same thing as sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
It is also neater I would say(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebk18257.aspx)

Comment: Be aware that the Environment.NewLine on unix systems is not "\r\n" so if you are implementing something specified as "\r\n" then you must write it in the code rather than calling AppendLine.

Comment: @hultqvist: Better to use `AppendLine` on a StreamWriter, then it will insert the newline sequence appropriate for that particular `StreamWriter` and not merely `Environment.NewLine`.  For example, if you open a stream tied to an SMTP connection, you can set its `NewLine` property to "\r\n" and then you'll get valid SMTP handshake even on Unix.

Comment: AppendLine is simpler than this method.

Comment: Use AppendLine as mentioned in the answer by Lijo below

Answer (score 83):

With [the AppendLine method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline).

َََ

Comment: This would be nice if it had the same number of overloads as Append(). Looks like an oversight.

Answer (score 27):

Also, using the [StringBuilder.AppendLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline.aspx) method.

Answer (score 13):

Use StringBuilder's append line built-in functions:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("First line");
sb.AppendLine("Second line");
sb.AppendLine("Third line");
```

#### Output

```
First line
Second line
Third line
```

Answer (score 6):

It will append `\n` in Linux instead `\r\n`.

Comment: My application is running in Linux but I want it return \r\n and I am currently using stringbuilder.AppendLine.

Answer (score 3):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

You can use **sb.AppendLine()** or **sb.Append(Environment.NewLine)**;

Answer (score 1):

For multiple lines the best way I find is to do this:

```
        IEnumerable<string> lines = new List<string>
        {
            string.Format("{{ line with formatting... {0} }}", id),
            "line 2",
            "line 3"
        };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(var line in lines)
            sb.AppendLine(line);
```

In this way you don't have to clutter the screen with the Environment.NewLine or AppendLine() repeated multiple times. It will also be less error prone than having to remember to type them.

Answer (score 1):

Just create an extension for the StringBuilder class:

```
Public Module Extensions
    <Extension()>
    Public Sub AppendFormatWithNewLine(ByRef sb As System.Text.StringBuilder, ByVal format As String, ParamArray values() As Object)
        sb.AppendLine(String.Format(format, values))
    End Sub
End Module
```