# How to add append "\n" to StringBuilder to get values in next line?

Tags: java

I have a edit pop up window.In my code  i'm using String Builder . I have used append for '.'  . My messages are ending with '.' i.e dot. How can i use "\n" so that my messages should come in next line?
 i have tried historyMessage.append("\n"),historyMessage.append("\n") and historyMessage.append("\r\n"); but it did not work for me . Can anyone please review my code and help where i'm wrong.

```
private String historyMessage(HdiGdvHistory hdiGdvHistory, String messageType) {
        StringBuilder historyMessage = new StringBuilder();
        HdiGdv gdv = hdiGdvDAO.getById(hdiGdvHistory.getHdiGdvId());
        hdiGdvHistoryList = hdiGdvHistoryDAO.getByIds(gdv.getId());
        if("approved".equals(messageType)  || "rejected".equals(messageType)){
            historyMessage.append("User "+hdiGdvHistory.getUser().getFirstName() +" has "+messageType);
        }

        if(hdiGdvHistoryList==null || hdiGdvHistoryList.isEmpty()){     
            if(!gdv.getHouseNumber().equals(hdiGdvHistory.getHouseNumber())){
                historyMessage.append(getHistoryMessage(hdiGdvHistory, "House Number" ,gdv.getHouseNumber(),hdiGdvHistory.getHouseNumber()));
                historyMessage.append(". ");
            }
        }else{
            hdiGdvHistoryList = hdiGdvHistoryDAO.getByFilteredIds(gdv.getId());
            System.out.println("list "+hdiGdvHistoryList.size());

            hdiGdvHistoryList = hdiGdvHistoryDAO.getByIds(gdv.getId());
            for (HdiGdvHistory history : hdiGdvHistoryList) {
                if(!hdiGdvHistory.getHouseNumber().equals(history.getHouseNumber())){
                    historyMessage.append(getHistoryMessage(hdiGdvHistory, "House Number" ,history.getHouseNumber(),hdiGdvHistory.getHouseNumber()));
                    historyMessage.append(". ");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }


    if(hdiGdvHistoryList==null || hdiGdvHistoryList.isEmpty()){
        if(!gdv.getCity().equals(hdiGdvHistory.getCity())){
            historyMessage.append(getHistoryMessage(hdiGdvHistory, "City" ,gdv.getCity(),hdiGdvHistory.getCity()));
            historyMessage.append(". ");
        }
    }else{
        for (HdiGdvHistory history : hdiGdvHistoryList) {
            if(!hdiGdvHistory.getCity().equals(history.getCity())){
                historyMessage.append(getHistoryMessage(hdiGdvHistory, "City" ,history.getCity(),hdiGdvHistory.getCity()));
                historyMessage.append(". ");
                break;
            }
        }
    }

       hdiGdvHistoryList.clear();
    gdv=new HdiGdv();
    hdiGdvHistory = new HdiGdvHistory();
    return historyMessage.toString();

}

private String getHistoryMessage(HdiGdvHistory hdiGdvHistory, String values , String preFieldValue ,String fieldValues ) {
        return "User "+hdiGdvHistory.getUser().getFirstName() +" has updated  " +values+ "  "+preFieldValue +" to "+fieldValues;
}
```

Comment: By just looking at the title. i'd say  **`StringBuilder.append("\n")`**

Comment: Looks like similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617752/newline-character-in-stringbuilder

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
historyMessage.append('\n');
```

Comment: see also [Java 7's lineSeparator method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator%28%29)